# how to get cell value from gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
protected void CovidSelfDecleartionDeatils_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        ShowallRecord();
        if (e.CommandArgument != "")
        {
            int Index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
         if (e.CommandName=="Select")
        {
            DataTable dt_main = new DataTable();

            dt_main = (DataTable)ViewState["ReportData"];
     
            GridViewRow clickedRow = CovidSelfDecleartionDeatils.Rows[Index];

            Session["Filepath"] = clickedRow.Cells[9].Text;
            //Session["Filepath"] = CovidSelfDecleartionDeatils.Rows[Index].FindControl("FilePath");
            Session["Filepath1"] = CovidSelfDecleartionDeatils.DataKeys[Index]["Filepath"].ToString();
            string filepath = Session["Filepath"].ToString();
            //DataGridViewSelectedRowCollection rows = dataGridView1.SelectedRows;
            //string val = (string)rows[2].Cells["Late_Time"].Value;
        }
        }
    }
    catch
    {
    }
}
```

```
<asp:GridView ID="CovidSelfDecleartionDeatils" runat="server" DataKeyNames="EmployeeCode" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        BackColor="#333333" CellPadding="5" CellSpacing="3" ForeColor="Black"  Width="100%" Height="300px"  OnRowCommand="CovidSelfDecleartionDeatils_RowCommand" >
    <Columns>
        

       
     <%--   <asp:BoundField DataField="InitiateMPPId" HeaderText="InitiateMPPId" >
            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        </asp:BoundField>--%>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="EmployeeCode" HeaderText="EmployeeCode" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" Visible="false"
         HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" ControlStyle-BorderStyle="None" ItemStyle-CssClass="per10" 
        HeaderStyle-CssClass="header-center">
  </asp:BoundField>
       <%-- <asp:BoundField DataField="EmployeeCode" HeaderText="EmployeeCode" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" Visible="false"
         HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" ControlStyle-BorderStyle="None" ItemStyle-CssClass="per10" 
        HeaderStyle-CssClass="header-center">
  </asp:BoundField>--%>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="EmpName" HeaderText="Employee"  ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" >
       
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Decleartion_Date" HeaderText="Date Decleartion"  ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" DataFormatString="{0:dd-MM-yyyy}" >
       
        </asp:BoundField>
         <asp:BoundField DataField="Ferver" HeaderText="Ferver"   ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Cough" HeaderText="Cough"   ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"/>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Breathlessness" HeaderText="Breathlessness"  ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"/>
         
       
        <asp:BoundField DataField="OtherDiseases" HeaderText="OtherDiseases" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" ItemStyle-CssClass="per50" ItemStyle-Height="25" HeaderStyle-Height="25" HeaderStyle-CssClass="header-center" HeaderStyle-Wrap="true"/>
          <asp:BoundField DataField="FileName" HeaderText="FileName" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" ItemStyle-CssClass="per50" ItemStyle-Height="25" HeaderStyle-Height="25" HeaderStyle-CssClass="header-center" HeaderStyle-Wrap="true" Visible="false" />
         <asp:BoundField DataField="DeclarationID" HeaderText="DeclarationID" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" ItemStyle-CssClass="per50" ItemStyle-Height="25" HeaderStyle-Height="25" HeaderStyle-CssClass="header-center" HeaderStyle-Wrap="true" Visible="false" />
         <asp:BoundField DataField="FilePath" HeaderText="FilePathfordownload" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" ItemStyle-CssClass="per50" ItemStyle-Height="25" HeaderStyle-Height="25" HeaderStyle-CssClass="header-center" HeaderStyle-Wrap="true" Visible="false" />
          <asp:BoundField DataField="ContactwithCovid" HeaderText="Incontact with covid patient Last(14) days" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" ItemStyle-CssClass="per50" ItemStyle-Height="25" HeaderStyle-Height="25" HeaderStyle-Width="15%" HeaderStyle-CssClass="header-center" HeaderStyle-Wrap="true"/>
        
          <%--<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:ImageButton ID="btn_delete_record"
                    Width="20px" Height="20px" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Content/Images/NewIcons/PDF.png" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>--%>
         <asp:ButtonField CommandName="Select" ControlStyle-CssClass="button" ButtonType="Image" ImageUrl="~/Content/Images/NewIcons/PDF.png"
                 ItemStyle-Width="5px" HeaderText="Download Attachment" />
        
           <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City"  ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" />
           <asp:BoundField DataField="TravelDate" HeaderText="TravelDate"  ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" DataFormatString="{0:dd-MM-yyyy}" />
         <asp:BoundField DataField="StateName" HeaderText="StateName"  ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" />
      
    </Columns>
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5e5d5d" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="White" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#000099" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1F1F1" />
    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="Gray" />
    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#CAC9C9" />
    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#383838" />
</asp:GridView>
```

what wrong in my showing excetion " Object reference is not set" when i am saving value in session

Comment: Did you checked clickedRow has 10 cell

Comment: Yes, In cell getting value but i want 9 cell value which is visible false?

Comment: Please can you share aspx code

Comment: please Check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove `visible=false` and define new css class  like

```
.donotshow { display: none; }
```

and add it `HeaderStyle-CssClass` and `ItemStyle-CssClass`